# Linux bash script acting weird

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a simple bash script that is suppose to monitor if mysql is up or down. If it is down, i want to also stop HAProxy from running. Below is my simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

nc -z 127.0.0.1 3306
rt_val=$?
msg=$(sudo service haproxy stop);
if [ $rt_val != 0 ]; then
    eval $msg
    exit 3
else
    exit 0
fi
```

The MySQL running or not part is working just fine. It is the stopping HAProxy part that seems to have an issue. What is happening is that HAProxy stops when mysql stops. But when i fire up MySQL and also HAProxy, it seems like the script continues to stop HAProxy even if MySQL is up and running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your script, you are **unconditionally** executing `sudo service haproxy stop` and storing the output in `$msg` using command substitution.

You could store the command in a variable, but this is considered very bad practice (see [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)). Instead, try assigning the command to a function and calling it later (the `function` keyword is both optional and Bash-specific, leave it out for portability):

```
#!/bin/bash

function stopcmd() { sudo service haproxy stop ; } # semicolon needed if on single line

nc -z 127.0.0.1 3306
rt_val=$?

if [ $rt_val != 0 ]; then
    stopcmd
    exit 3
else
    exit 0
fi
```

Furthermore, neither the function nor the test (`[ ... ]`) is really necessary in this simple case. Your script can be written as:

```
#!/bin/bash 

if nc -z 127.0.0.1 3306
then
    exit 0
else
    sudo service haproxy stop
    exit 3
fi
```

Comment: Recommending storage of a command in a string is not a good idea. A function or array is **much** better and robust. See [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for more details about this issue. (It works for this simple case but fails for more complicated ones so best to just always avoid it.)

Comment: Thanks Michael. Using the function works. The second piece code actually does not.

Comment: @TheGeorgia: Oh, sorry, I kept the `then` to myself :)

Comment: Just FYI. There's no need for the `function` keyword and it is non-portable/non-POSIX.

Comment: @EtanReisner: I know. But you're right, I think I'll add a note on that. I am used to the non-portable style because it marks a function more clearly than `()`. Most shell programs I wrote were used in an environment where readability and changeability were very important, while portability was not - all target platforms were guaranteed to provide a certain minimum Bash version. I know that it is the other way around for many people programming shells.

Comment: Thanks Eta for your extra info. Will make necessary updates to the suggestion provided by Michael.